# Como usar el patrón agregado en este caso

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estoy en un dilema con el patrón `Agregado` la cuestión es que tengo dos entidades

```
public class PayCenter : BaseVersionedEntity<Guid>
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsIndicator { get; set; }
    public Guid AreaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Area Area { get; set; }
}

public class Area : BaseVersionedEntity<Guid>
{   
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsMultiCenter { get; set; }
    public bool IsIndicator { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PayCenter> PayCenters { get; set; }
}
```

Tengo las siguientes dudas:

1. Si pongo el área como entidad `root`, lo cual deriva a tener un repositorio, como puedo acceder a todos mis centros desde la capa de servicio, sin tener que pasar por todas las áreas.
2. Si dejo las dos entidades como `root`, es valido tener dos repositorios y crear un centro de pago usando un área previamente obtenida?
3. Debería tener 1 o  2 agregados para este caso?

Comment: estas seguro que el Area es tu root ?

Answer (score 1):

Para que una entidad sea considerada un *Aggregate root* debe cumplir con las sgtes condiciones (Según el libro [Domain Driven Design de Erick Evans](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215)):

- Tener identidad global y ser responsable por validar las invariantes.

  Ninguna de las dos clases tiene lógica asociada por lo que no se puede hablar de entidades. Es más solo parecen representar un mapeo de entidades posiblemente para que funcione con un ORM. Validar las invariantes significa por ejemplo si es que existe una lógica que verifique cuantos `PayCenter` como máximo pueden estar asociados a un `Area` esta debería ser validada en un método `AddPayCenter`pertenceciente a la clase `Area`
- La entidad raiz debe tener identidad global, las entidades dentro del agregado deben tener solo identidad local dentro del agregado.

  Según el código parece faltar una propiedada `AreaId` en la clase `Area`. Además las propiedades `Code` de ambos parece indicar que ambos tienen identidad propia por lo que pueden ser accedidos separadamente.
- Nada fuera del límite del agregado puede mantenere referencias a nada de adentro excepto a la entidad raíz. La entidad raíz puede entregar referencias de entidades internas a otros objetos sólo si son usados temporalmente en un solo método o bloque.

  Esto no es posible de verificar solo con el código mostrado
- Solo los aggregate roots pueden ser obtenidos directamente usando queries de base de datos. El resto debe ser accedido recorriendo las relaciones entre entidades

  Si ambas entidades son agregados de una única entidad cada una debería tener su propio repositorio. Si solo `Area` es un aggregate root entonces se debe acceder a los PayCenter únicamente a través del Area y no necesitar su propio repositorio.
- Los objetos dentro del agregado pueden mantener referencias a otros agregados

  Esta restricción se esta cumpliendo
- Una operación de eliminación debe remover todo el agregado en una única operación.

  No es posible determinar esto con el código presentado
- Cuando un cambio a un objeto dentro del agregado es "commiteado" todas las invariantes del agregado deben ser satisfechas.

  Las entidades no tienen lógica alguna así que no se puede determinar si esto se cumple o no.

Respondiendo tus preguntas:

1. Si pongo el área como entidad root, lo cual deriva a tener un repositorio, como puedo acceder a todos mis centros desde la capa de servicio, sin tener que pasar por todas las áreas.

   Según DDD estrictamente hablando esto no debería ser posible. Si necesitas hacer esto los `PayCenter` no deberían formar parte del agregado de `Area`
2. Si dejo las dos entidades como root, es valido tener dos repositorios y crear un centro de pago usando un área previamente obtenida?

   Si, no hay restricciones en ese sentido así que si es válido
3. Debería tener 1 o 2 agregados para este caso?

   Bueno esto depende de lo que tratas de lograr. Al parecer necesitas acceder directamente a los `PayCenter` sin pasar por `Area` por lo que probablemente debes modelarlo como dos agregados separados.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que planteas parece ser que el `Area` no representa el `root` del `agregate`.

Quizas deba ser algun otro concepto el que una la forma de interactuar entre el `area` y los `centros de pago`, eso deberias buscarlo con los expertos del dominio.

O por ahi no exista ningun concepto que los agrupe y sean dos entidades separadas que simplemte se relacionan entre si. Si este es el caso vas a tener dos repositorios uno para cada entidad.

[Effective Aggregate Design](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=838)

El tema es que cuando usas `entity framework` vas a poder implemetar el `Include()` por lo que recuperando el area tambien vas a poder obtener en la misma operacion la lista de `paycenter` asociada.

[Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

Cuando modelas UML seguro conoces que existen varias formas de asociar las entidades, podrian ser `agregates` o `composition` segun que tanto dependa el ciclo de vida de una entidad respecto de su relacion con otra. Aqui tiene que ver como se eliminan las relaciones.

[UML Class Diagram: Association, Aggregation and Composition](http://aviadezra.blogspot.com.ar/2009/05/uml-association-aggregation-composition.html)